# SimpleSAMLphp does not work with memcache, whitescreens appear

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-7, memcached, simplesamlphp

Version information: Drupal 7.50, SimpleSAMLphp 1.14.4 , Memcache 3.0.8 and php 5.6.24

I’m currently making a single sign on using simplesamlphp with memcache. I want to be able to login to my drupal site using something like www.example.com/saml_login.

Simplesamlphp works perfect when using 'store.type' => 'phpsession', which makes it possible to log in to the SP. But when I change the the store.type to 'store.type' => 'memcache',  in config/config.php, which is needed to use the simplesamlphp_auth module(https://www.drupal.org/project/simplesamlphp_auth), all simplesaml pages, like www.example.com/simplesaml, turn in to whitescreens.

Memcache is installed on my Drupal site and according to the status report it is installed successfully.

What might help to solve the whitescreem problem? Did anyone had a similar problem?

Thanks in advance.

Update 1:
After a long search I might have found the error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '/home/example/var/simplesamlphp/config/config.php: The option 'memcache_store.prefix' is not a valid string value.' in /home/example/var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Configuration.php:604\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/example/var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Store/Memcache.php(26): SimpleSAML_Configuration->getString('memcache_store....', 'simpleSAMLphp')\n#1 /home/example/var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Store.php(46): SimpleSAML_Store_Memcache->__construct()\n#2 /home/example/var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/SessionHandler.php(109): SimpleSAML_Store::getInstance()\n#3 /home/example/var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/SessionHandler.php(39): SimpleSAML_SessionHandler::createSessionHandler()\n#4 /home/example/var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Session.php(143): SimpleSAML_SessionHandler::getSessionHandler()\n#5 /home/example/var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Session.php(328): SimpleSAML_Session->__construct(true)\n#6 /home/example...\nPHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '/home/example/var/simplesamlphp/config/config.php: The option 'memcache_store.prefix' is not a valid string value.' in /home/example/var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Configuration.php:604\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/example/var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Store/Memcache.php(26): SimpleSAML_Configuration->getString('memcache_store....', 'simpleSAMLphp')\n#1 /home/example/var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Store.php(46): SimpleSAML_Store_Memcache->__construct()\n#2 /home/example/var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/SessionHandler.php(109): SimpleSAML_Store::getInstance()\n#3 /home/example/var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/SessionHandler.php(39): SimpleSAML_SessionHandler::createSessionHandler()\n#4 /home/example/var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Session.php(143): SimpleSAML_SessionHandler::getSessionHandler()\n#5 /home/example/var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Session.php(328): SimpleSAML_Session->__construct(true)\n#6 /home/example...\n'

Comment: Check php.ini file - is error reporting and logging enabled. White screen usually means that error reporting is turned off.

Comment: Error reporting and logging are enabled. Also the error logging of simplesaml and memcache is turned on.

Comment: Voted down and for closing as the question is not about programming and include an error message that clearly indicate this is a configuration issue (as confirmed by the author's own answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplesamlphp config/config.php the memcache_store.prefix was edited from "null" to "SimpleSAMLphp" which made the whitescreens disappear.

Note that this shouldn't actually be necessary, the default value of "null" should work just fine. See bug: https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/issues/496